# How to display default value for enum?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this dropdown list :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Register.DocType, 
Enum.GetNames(typeof(BetX.Shared.Enums.UserDocumentType)).Select(n => new SelectListItem { 
Text = n, Value = n, Selected = n == Enum.GetName(typeof(BetX.Shared.Enums.UserDocumentType), Model.Register.DocType) }),"Please select")
```

I want to display default value when i run application "Please select" but i always get first value.How can i do that? When i click on dropdown list i can see that value(Please select)

Comment: You binding to property `Register.DocType` so you need to make the property nullable.

Comment: u mean this m=>m.Register.DocType ?

Comment: No I mean in your model it needs to be `public UserDocumentType? DocType { get; set; }` (or `Nullable<UserDocumentType>`)